# Cannot insert pdf file into MySQL db as BLOB

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have express app that should take filename and inserts file in db that way:

```
var file = fs.readFileSync('filename.*');
db.query('INSERT INTO table (file) VALUES (?)', file, (err,result)=>{
  if(err) throw err;
})
```

"file" column has BLOB type.

So the problem is it works correct with `*.jpg` files, but when I'm trying to do the same thing with `*.pdf` file it seems like it works, but when I'm opening phpmyadmin panel I see not `BLOB` and not `NULL`, just an empty field where should be `[BLOB-*KB]`. I think I need to convert pdf file to binary format, but I don't know how.

Comment: How big is your PDF file?

Comment: @zoonman <10KB. As I know it must be ok if the size of BLOB is less than 64KB